# Question about definition of regular projection of a knot

Tags: definition, knot-theory

One can define a knot in two ways:

(1) A knot is a closed polygonal curve in $\mathbb R^3$

(2) A knot is an equivalence class of embeddings $S^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^3$

And perhaps also:

(3) A knot is an equivalence class of smooth $1$-dimensional submanifolds of $S^3$

Question 1: Can I replace $S^3$ in (3) with $\mathbb R^3$?

Question 2: I would like to define what a regular projection of a knot is. Unfortunately, it depends on whether I use (1), (2) or (3). I would like to use (2) and I have the definition using (1), which goes as follows:

(Definition) A knot projection is called a *regular* if no three points on the knot project to the same point, and no vertex projects to the same point as any other point on the knot.

How can I define *regular projection* without (1), that is, how can I define it for embeddings instead of polygonal curves?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: None of these constitutes a definition of a knot. The content of the definition is in the equivalence relation on these objects whose equivalence classes actually define knots (namely ambient isotopy).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry, I'm getting confused. For example, in Kauffman's "On knots" on the first page (page 3) he writes "... Classical knot theory studies embeddings of $S^1$ in $\mathbb R^3$ ...".

Comment: Knot theory studies equivalence classes of such embeddings under ambient isotopy. Kauffman is being mildly imprecise.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Lickorish also (on the first page) defines it to be a subset of $\mathbb R^3$ that is a piecewise linear simple closed curve. Then he is also being imprecise? (Same in Livingston's Knot Theory, page 15). Can you point me to a precise definition?

Comment: Yes and yes. A knot is an equivalence class of embeddings of $S^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ up to ambient isotopy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_isotopy). These equivalence classes can also be represented by piecewise linear curves, by smooth curves, or by any other reasonable kind of curve, which is why it doesn't matter which kind of curves you take.

Comment: Another way of addressing the concern I'm raising here is to define the category of knots to be the category whose objects are embeddings of $S^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ and whose morphisms are ambient isotopies. Then a knot should refer to an object in this category, but up to isomorphism as is usual in category theory. But if you haven't said something equivalent to "ambient isotopy" then you haven't captured arguably the most important part of what people mean when they say "knot."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for the input. I will post an answer later.

Comment: While Qiaochu Yuan raises a good point, your post also seems to contain some other concerns: (a) How to define a knot diagram precisely, (b) how to prove that the notion of knot diagrams makes sense in the first place and (c) how to recognize whether two knots are ambient isotopic using the diagrams. The connection is provided by Reidemeister's theorem: two knots (or links) are ambient isotopic iff they have diagrams that can be transformed into each other by a sequence of Reidemeister moves. [This MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15217/) contains a few references, maybe they help.

Comment: @commenter Thank you!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I corrected the definitions in my question but my question remains: assume I use the definition for knot that says it's an equivalence class of embeddings, how can I define regular projection? I can't use the word "vertex" in the def. of regular projection unless I use definition (1) for knots, or can I?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Reading the first paragraph [here](http://www.ams.org/staff/jackson/fea-nelson.pdf) suggests that one can either view knots as equivalence classes or as simple closed curves!

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you can replace $\mathbf R^3$ with $S^3$ everywhere and it will essentially not make a difference. Your assumptions imply that the knot misses a point which you can add/remove to go back and forth between either one. This MO question might be stimulating: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63158/
2. A definition if the embedding is smooth (or just differentiable)  is that a projection is regular if the composite map $\phi \colon S^1 \to \mathbf R^2$ has the property that no three points are mapped to the same point, and that if $\phi(p)=\phi(q)$, then nonzero tangent vectors at $p$ and $q$ are mapped to linearly independent tangent vectors under $d\phi$. In other words, the image of the knot crosses itself transversely.

Comment: Thank you! Would you point me to a book/notes or other reference where you got this definition from?

Comment: @RudytheReindeer A discussion about some of these things at the elementary level can be found in the first three chapters of the book _Knots and Links_ by Peter Cromwell.